# mod_rewrite not matching simple redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a weird issue with `mod_rewrite`. My website is set up in such a way that the user can access a translated version of the webpage via a URL like `example.com/pt/about` or just access the normal page like so `example.com/about`, to accomplish this I have the following in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(en|pt)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/about/?$ about.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/contact/?$ contact.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

In my development machine I'm running XAMPP 3.2.2 with Apache 2.4.29 and in my production server I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with Apache 2.4.18. In my development machine everything works fine, if I try to visit `/about` it shows me `about.php` and if I try `/pt/about` it translates the page to portuguese as is the correct behavior, but in the production server if I try to visit `/about` I get a 404 error, but if I try to visit `/pt/about` it displays the page correctly without any issues.

Why is this happening and how I might correct it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a relative path.

This directive is required when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless any of the following conditions are true:

1. The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).
2. The file system path to the directory containing the RewriteRule, suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on the server (this is rare).
3. In Apache HTTP Server 2.4.16 and later, this directive may be omitted when the request is mapped via Alias or mod_userdir.

I think the problem is the configuration difference and it will be solved by adding `RewriteBase /` to your code, so it should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(en|pt)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/about/?$ about.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/contact/?$ contact.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Just tried this and apparently it made no difference, this is really a strange issue.

Comment: ok , try to clear browser cache and test it again , if nothing  let me know, i want to do some changes in all code

Comment: Tried everything possible, including trying it on a different machine, nothing seems to work.